Is $A^t P_{im(A)} v = A^t v$?
Let $A$ be an $m×n$ matrix. Doesn't need to be square.
Consider a vector $v ∈ \Bbb{R}^m$ and the projection $P : im(A) ⊕ im(A)^⊥ \to im(A)$.
Then is it the case that $A^t P v = A^t v$ ?
I know that $im(A) = ker(A^t)^\perp$, but I don't know how to proceed with this.

Yes.
Let $v=v_{A}+v_\perp$ where $v_{⊥}\in im(A)^⊥, v_{A}\in im(A)$.
So $A^{t}v=A^{t}(v_{A}+v_\perp)=A^{t}Pv+A^{t}v_{\perp}$.
So only need to prove $A^{t}v_{\perp}=0$.
So only need $0=(A^{t}v_{\perp})^{t}=(v_{\perp})^{t}A$.
So only need $\forall w, 0=(v_{\perp})^{t}Aw$.
By definition it is true.
